# Counting the Total Number of Local Minima for a Multivariate Function

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, computational-statistics

Is it possible to count the total number of local minima for a scalar, multivariate function? We can assume the function is differentiable, but it is also non-convex and setting the gradient equal to zero has no analytical solution.

We may also assume that the domain is bounded, namely the variables in the domain sum to unity: $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n \leq 1$ and $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$. Furthermore, the maximum number of local minima is equal to the number of variables, $n$.

I was thinking of using some sampling method like either just sampling the entire space or using some MCMC method; however, if there is some noise that is finer than the grid spacing then even this won't work (something like this: [http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~ama132/images/test1.svg](http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/%7Eama132/images/test1.svg))

Could there be some computational methods from machine/deep learning that might be helpful here? Or maybe some analytical methods from mathematics? I think the part I'm struggling with is making sure I've counted ALL the local minima (critical points is also fine).

If it helps, the function I'm considering is quite simple. It's just the sum of an entropy term with an energy term, namely, $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_ilogx_i +  \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_iX_{ij}x_j$, where $X$ is a symmetric interaction matrix of real number scalars with diagonal zero.

Comment: It is always possible to imagine a function with a number of local maxima larger than the number of MCMC iterations.

Comment: @Xi'an for my problem the maximum number of local minima is equal to the number of variables in the input space. My issue is with counting all the local minima without knowing how many there may be

Comment: Note that MCMC is not an optimisation algorithm, hence it would not be appropriate to identify all the modes of a distribution (made out of the function to minimise). A typical example is a Gibbs sampler for mixture posteriors, which usually sticks to one mode out of $k!$, $k$ being the number of components. The closest solution is simulated annealing, which forces a stochastic process to spend more and more time near the modes, but it cannot guarantee a certain identification of _all_ the modes.